# Remove element from array containing empty or whitespace character in Perl

Tags: perl, dictionary, grep

I want to transform array @x into array @y using map or grep.

```
@x = ('aa','', 'bb','    ','cc', "\t");
@y = ('aa','bb','cc');
```

What i have tried :

```
#@x= grep {s/^\s+|\s+$//g} @x;  # not correct
@y = grep { $_ } @x;  # remove '' null character
```

Please suggest better way to do this, preferably in one line.

Comment: Please show the results of those two attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. the first `grep` is sufficient, But doing a substitution in `grep` seems odd, better use `map` for this. See `grep` as a *filter*.
   See what perlcritic 'thinks' about the substitution in `grep` :

   > `$ perlcritic -5 test.pl`
   >   `test.pl: Don't modify $_ in list functions at line 6, column 6.
   >   See page 114 of PBP.  (Severity: 5, Policy:
   >   ControlStructures::ProhibitMutatingListFunctions)`

   `5` is the most permissive, and the best practice is to apply at least this level (or less)
2. always put `use strict; use warnings;` near the beginning of your Perl programs.
3. put `$_` in the grep to output something : `grep {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_ }`

Finally :

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @x = ('aa','', 'bb','    ','cc', '\t');
my @y = ('aa','bb','cc');

@x = grep {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_ } @x;
print join "\n", @x;
```

But the `grep` can be written simply as

```
grep { /\S/ } @x
```

#### OUTPUT :

```
aa
bb
cc
\t
```

Comment: Making substitutions in `grep` seems a little convoluted for such a simple operation; why not just `grep { /\S/ }` or something like that?

Comment: Op code has side effect since grep aliases $_, but probably he is not aware of that https://eval.in/238434

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like you just want

```
@y = grep /\S/, @x;
```